# How to check status of hdfs job from java program?

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

I want to check the status of a job. Once it is completed I want to perform another action. The problem is I also want to check whether job is killed or aborted as many jobs can be there in hdfs and report accordingly.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobStatus
Gone through the link! Aslo please saw the source code on this link.

```
private void printJobAnalysis() {
 if (!job.getJobStatus().equals
  (JobStatus.getJobRunState(JobStatus.SUCCEEDED))) {
System.out.println("No Analysis available as job did not finish");
return;
```

}

```
AnalyzedJob avg = new AnalyzedJob(job);

System.out.println("\nAnalysis");
System.out.println("=========");
printAnalysis(avg.getMapTasks(), cMap, "map", avg.getAvgMapTime(), 
10);
printLast(avg.getMapTasks(), "map", cFinishMapRed);

if (avg.getReduceTasks().length > 0) {
 printAnalysis(avg.getReduceTasks(), cShuffle, "shuffle", 
    avg.getAvgShuffleTime(), 10);
 printLast(avg.getReduceTasks(), "shuffle", cFinishShuffle);

 printAnalysis(avg.getReduceTasks(), cReduce, "reduce",
    avg.getAvgReduceTime(), 10);
 printLast(avg.getReduceTasks(), "reduce", cFinishMapRed);
}
System.out.println("=========");
}
```